# PHP send stream to browser as zip archive

Tags: php, http-headers, zip

I am making a call(PHP server) to an API and I can confirm that I am getting a response, my code at the point where I know I am getting a response is:

```
$binaryF = $rsObject->makeCall('get', "/JobData/{$_GET["jID"]}", "?format=bin");

//header("Pragma: public"); // required
//header("Content-Type: application/zip");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ss.zip");
//header("Content-Length: " . filesize($binaryF.length));
//header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

file_put_contents('C:\ss.zip', $binaryF);
```

If I keep the code as is and click on the link that takes me to the page with this code on it, ss.zip is created and I open it and confirm that it has the correct content. The data is coming from an API call on the first line and is basically a zip package. If I remove the comments and comment out the file_put_contents line then the browser opens a file save dialog box but if I save it the archive is 0 bytes?

How do I send the content to a browser after retrieving it from the api call? I do not want to save it to disk first, I want to send it to the browser making the request directly.

Thank you
Jack

Ok. I changed it to:

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ss.zip");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($binaryF));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

and now it opens the file save. I save it and it is 8 K but when I try t oopen it I get a message of: "Windows cannot open the folder" It complains that the zip is invalid? At least I am getting somewhere, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @zerkms - It is the length of the content. If I remove the header comment I cannot confirm the lenght...

Comment: What is var_dump of $binaryF?

Comment: @Jack Smit: actually `$binaryF.length` is a variable `$binaryF` concatenated with `length` constant.

Comment: k, .lenght did not work..... let me check var_dump

Comment: You want to use `strlen($binaryF)` instead

Comment: @zerkms - what? I do not understand please?

Comment: @Jack Smit: what actually you don't understand?

Comment: echo strlen($binaryF); produce a value of 63929410. Let me see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Jack Smit: now check if all the headers are correct (in the browser)

Comment: @Jack Smit: and what do you see if you open your file in any editor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18999/discussion-between-jack-smit-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=ss.zip');

echo $binaryF;
```

Comment: why don't you pass Content-Length?

Comment: @zerkms: In this context, what impact does length have?

Comment: it's a good idea to always include it. As well as specifying correct content type, `application/zip` in this case

Comment: Perhaps, but in this case it seems like it's a straight pass thru, simply hand off to the browser what was retrieved from the api.

Comment: how passing through makes an exception for that? The string is 60M+ long.

Comment: I'm still not sure benefits knowing the strlen will provide? The browser will download the file regardless of filesize...

Comment: user will know how much is left. The browser progress bar relies on the content length.

Comment: I'm working on a similar project, I am not providing the content-length and chrome is handling the download just fine, as well as progress. Perhaps it's browser specific?

Comment: it's not possible *by definition*. If browser doesn't know how long the content is - it cannot estimate the progress. Just check the headers, I'm sure something passes the length automatically on the server.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not explicitly stating content length, and the download still works.

Answer (score 0):

`$binaryF` would need to be a string value for the filepath to the file you are trying to serve up in order for `filesize()` to work.

You can use `strlen()` to get the filesize for use in the ContentLength header.

You of course still need to actually output the file to the client browser.

Comment: "Otehrwise you will need to get the file on disk in order to determine the file size." --- lol what? `strlen()`

Comment: @Mike Purcell: http://php.net/strlen. You don't need to save a string to a file to get the string length, just believe me.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, I really didn't pay attention top  the last line of the code example I guess. I was thinking in terms of him getting a stream and wanting to pass that stream directly through to client, rather than getting the full binary string in memory and then passing it to client browser. I have revised accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems with PDF's, for me the `Content-Length` couldn't be calculated correctly with `strlen()` because it doesn't support `multibyte-characters`.

instead try this:

```
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($binaryF));
```

See the documentation for more detailed information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: You're wrong. As long as the string contents binary data - it's a one-byte encoded (as any other binary). Multibyte is only applied for text

Comment: @zerkms On second thought, are you sure; because it's binary isn't it even more critical to get an accurate count, since the information is still passed as a String.

Comment: yes I'm sure. multibyte is only true for encodings that have several bytes for character. In binary every character is a byte. And because it is binary - `strlen` would count number of bytes which equals to number of characters

Answer (score 0):

Ok, @zerkms helped me by pointing out that I should use: strlen($binaryF) instead of filesize($binaryF.length) He helped me in a chat session by telling me to open the zip archive(with something simple like notepad) that I did get with file_put_contents('C:\ss.zip', $binaryF); This showed that what was produced was only partially correct, there was some HTML content that slipped into the response of the actual call. So all credit goes to @zerkms, thanks.

What worked? the following worked for me:

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ss.zip");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($binaryF.length));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

echo $binaryF
```